# Inspector stuck on Editor Settings

Tags: unity

Probably a silly question, but I'm having an issue where I can't view the properties of an object in the inspector window. It seems to be stuck on "Editor Settings". If I click an object I can't view its properties.

[image]

Any idea what's going on it's confused me for the past 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padlock in the top right corner of the image indicates that this inspector panel is in "locked" mode.

Clicking on this icon will toggle the lock on and off.

Further information on this feature is available on the manual page [Inspector Options](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html).